# Cannot resolve 'columnname' given input columns: Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark

I am running this code daily and I am saving the output on some chosen location:

```
  def aggConnections()(input: DataFrame) = {
    input
      .groupBy (
        $"spid" (0).as ("domain_userid"),
        $"cxid" (0).as ("key_id") )
      .agg (
        min ($"Time").as ("first_seen"),
        max ($"Time").as ("last_seen") )
      .select ($"domain_userid", $"key_id",
        lit ("cxense_id").as ("key_source"),
        lit (1).as ("times_seen"),
        $"first_seen", $"last_seen")
      .filter($"domain_userid".isNotNull && $"key_id".isNotNull)
  }

 val requests = spark.read.parquet("day1").transform(aggConnections())
```

`spid` is an array and it looks like this:

```
spid:array
     element:string
```

That's why I had to access it like `$"spid" (0).as ("domain_userid")`

Unfortunately, **on some days** I get the following error when running this job on AWS EMR running Spark 3.0.1:

> diagnostics: User class threw exception:
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`spid`' given
> input columns: [AdUnitId, AudienceSegmentIds, BandWidth,
> BandwidthGroupId, BandwidthId, Browser, BrowserId, City, CityId,
> CmsMetadata, Country, CountryId, DeviceCategory, Domain, GfpContentId,
> IsCompanion, IsFilledRequest, IsInterstitial, IsVideoFallbackRequest,
> KeyPart, Metro, MetroId, MobileAppId, MobileCapability, MobileCarrier,
> MobileDevice, OS, OSId, OSVersion, PodPosition, PostalCode,
> PostalCodeId, PublisherProvidedID, RefererURL, Region, RegionId,
> RequestLanguage, RequestedAdUnitSizes, Time, TimeUsec2, UserId,
> VideoPosition, addefend, ads_enabled, app_name, app_version,
> bereidingstijd, brand, careerlevel, cat, category, categorycode,
> categoryname, channel_id, channel_title, cid, cmssource, companyname,
> compid, content_url, contentid, contentsubstype, crt_cpm, crt_size,
> cxid, cxsg, dc_yt, deviceid, dos, dossier, educationlevel, floor, fsr,
> gang, gdpr_applies, gdpr_consentstring, gelegenheid, hb_pb, hb_size,
> hour, ifa, industry, ingredient, iom, itemid, ix_apnx_om, ix_cdb_om,
> ix_imdi_cpm, jobtitle, k21, kage, kar, kauth, kembed, keuken, kgender,
> klg, ko, kpid, kvlg, kvz, kw, lat, long, mc_asset_type, mediation,
> model, moeilijkheid, origin, pag, pagetype, path, pay, pos, positie,
> production_id, productname, retailercode, retailername, rpfl_12108,
> screen, sector, shopid, show_id, show_title, soort, src, stad,
> starttype, station, subforum, tag, theme, top, video_duration,
> video_label, yt_vrallowed, ytdevice];; 'Aggregate ['spid[0],
> cxid#136[0]], ['spid[0] AS domain_userid#276, cxid#136[0] AS
> key_id#277, min(Time#0) AS first_seen#417, max(Time#0) AS
> last_seen#419]

I thought the problem was because the `spid` column was not present, howerver it is in the data when I check the schema. Therfore, I decided to test it more accurately on Databricks. The weird thing is that If I run this code on Databricks running the same Spark version 3.0.1 everything works fine on every day of data, including the ones that fail on EMR. I really can't explain what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that my daily partitions were saved in hourly partitions too. The schemas of these hourly partitions may slightly differ in the way that some hours missed my `spid` column. Hence, on some days my production environment was failing with the error reported above.

The bug was difficult to spot because my test instance had the `option("mergeSchema", "true")` as a default Spark option, hence it was merging the schema without encountering the error.